# Как сделать редактирование ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

В общем, с ajax работать умею, но никак не могу понять как сделать это редактирование(Читал статьи, но там все непонятно, и то, нашел 1-2).
В общем, при клике подгружается нужный материал(сделал, но это делается не так).
При клике "сохранить" отправляются данные, и обновляются(сделаю).
Мне не понятен сам метод редактирование.
Т.е, пользователь нажимает на кнопку --- а далее? Я грузил инфу (с проверкой на пост пользователя конечно), но потом прочел, что нужно по другому.
Кто мог бы объяснить или кинуть ссылочку на статью где это расписывается? 
Т.е, мне нажатии "редактирование" нужно сделать инпут поля(по идеи) и считать информацию которую ввели(чтобы сохранить).
Юзаю jquery.
Спасибо.

Comment: Можете выложить задачу, как она есть? Требования и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если сохранение осуществляется по кнопке, например "Сохранить", то сделать можно так:
1. Кнопке "Сохранить" добавить аттрибут onclick:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="savePost()">Сохранить</a>
```

2. Функцию savePost() необходимо описать ввиде $.ajax:

```
function savePost()
{
    // если это input
    var newText = $('#edit_text').val();
    // если textarea, то закомментить строку выше, и раскомментировать ту, что ниже
    // var newText = $('#edit_text').text(); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/change_text.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { newText: newText },
        success: function (response) {
            alert('Сообщение отправлено на сервер');
        }
    });
}
```

Соответственно, на сервере, вы примете значение переменное в виде $_POST['newText'].
Все это я сильно упростил, но в целом как-то так...